# Find out user removed from which project in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I have removed an user from some TFS project group. But somehow i do not remember which is the project he has been removed from .

Is there a way to track back, which project that particular user was having access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no audit trail for security and this no way to know which group the user was removed from.